# Rails form_tag remote example

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this incredible simple form:

```
<%= form_tag("/portal/search", method: 'get', remote: true ) do %>

  <%= label_tag(:query, 'Search for:') %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:query) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Find") %>

<% end %>
<div id="results"></div>
```

I know from the documentation, I can use AJAX through the remote option:

```
<%= form_tag("/portal/search", method: 'get', remote: true ) do %>
```

Then I get stuck. I know how to generate results in a view/partial, but how do I get that partial inside the div element? I know a bit of JQuery, so I can select the element. I found a lot of results, but they seem to miss that lightbulb moment for me. I am using Rails **4.1.6**

My results are just simple records from a model, like Book (title, author)

Thank you for helping!

**EDIT**

I've won the cup for missing the point by a long shot. I had to add the search.js.erb inside the **view** folder instead of assets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's say you get `@results` out of your search method.

In the controller, search method:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {render or redirect_to wherever you need it}
  format.js 
end
```

Then all you need is a file named `search.js.erb` to run the required js at the end of your request. It might look something like:

```
$('#results_div').html("<%= j @results.pluck(:title).join('<br/>') %>")
```

Comment: okay - I guess I have to change it to something coffeescript like?

Comment: If you are using coffeescript yes, can't help you there as I personally don't use it. In the above I assumed you were using jQuery by the way, it would look slightly different in pure javascript.

Comment: do I have to add @results after the render statement (format.js) I still don't get results...

Comment: It seems the JS can't do its work because of a Nil class. Somewhere the @results must get passed to it, I guess :S

Comment: app/assets/javascripts/search.js.erb:4:in `block in singleton class'

Comment: Yes, the respond_to bit needs to come at the end of the search method. Before that, @results needs to be defined!

Comment: this was the answer all along. I missed to put the file name inside the VIEW folder.... :)

Answer (score 5):

When you add remote: true [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) will provide you the ajax request (by default this javascript lib is required in app/assets/javascripts/application.js).

The ajax call will request a 'text/javascript' response. for that reason your server code should reply with:

```
# action
def search_query
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { 
      # additional code
    }
  end
end
```

If in your view (`search_query.js.erb`) you provide javascript, it will be executed. That is why everyone is replying you with a `$('#my_div_id').html('my html text')` suggestion, which when executed will replace your div content with the new HTML.

If for some reason you want to return a json data structure, then you should provide a different data-type:

```
form_tag("/jquery_ujs/search_query", remote: true, 'data-type' => :json) do
  # ....
end
```

And you should reply with:

```
# action
def search_query
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json:  @my_object }
  end
end
```

And handle the success event:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#my_form").on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr) {
      console.log("Great!");

      // use data to access to your json data structure
    });

    $("form#my_form").on('ajax:error', function(event, xhr, status, error) {
      console.log("sorry mate!");
    });

    // ....
  })
</script>
```

You can also request a html response (in case you want to return a table, for instance), with `:'data-type' => :html` and `format.html { render layout: false }`

Comment: it might be a weird question, but the search.js.erb belongs in the assets folder right?

Comment: You are right, they belong to the view. Rails Knows which to call based on the server request and your format reply. You aren't an idiot ... take your time because it will be always hard :D.

Answer (score 1):

**Ajax**

Firstly, the [Rails UJS (unobtrusive javascript)](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) driver just gives you a "canned" way to send an ajax request to your browser. To avoid confusion, it's best to appreciate that you will be sending Ajax requests regardless of whether you use `Rails UJS` or the standard Ajax method

This means that the process of capturing the `response` from your Ajax is still the same - you need to make sure you have to catch the response from the system

Either :-

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("ajax:success", ".element", function(status, data, xhr) {
   // do something here
});
```

or

```
#app/controllers/portal_controller.rb
class PortalController < ApplicationController 
  def search
     respond_to do |format|
        format.js #-> app/views/portal/search.js.erb
        format.html
     end
  end
end

#app/views/portal/search.js.erb
//something here
```

---

**Fix**

> how do I get that partial inside the div element

You'll be able to use JS:

```
#app/controllers/portal_controller.rb
class PortalController < ApplicationController
   def search
      @results = ...
      respond_to do |format|
         format.js
         format.html
      end
   end
end

#app/views/portal/search.js.erb
$(".div").html("<%=j render @results %>");
```

Comment: one problem - render isn't available in assets... :(

Comment: Yes, but it *is* available in the views ;)