# Ruby on Rails - search results to show up on the current page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a search bar available on every page of the webapp by adding

```
  <body>
<%= form_tag(class_data_index_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search your major" %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  <% end %>

<%= yield %>
```

in application.html.erb.

When I search, it shows the results, but it also navigates to /class_data?search=SearchKeyword. I want the results to show up on the current page, whether it'd be /home, /anothermodel.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: yoy have to do it using ajax

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a remote form with `<%= form_tag remote: true %>` - see [Rails form_tag remote example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970335/rails-form-tag-remote-example) as an example and a starting point.